# Getting error 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' when implementing custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, keras, loss

I am using a custom Mean Average Precision error function in my keras model:

```
def apk(actual, predicted, k=3):
     actual = list(actual)
     predicted = list(predicted)
     if len(predicted)>k:
         predicted = predicted[:k]
     score = 0.0
     num_hits = 0.0
     for i,p in enumerate(predicted):
         if p in actual and p not in predicted[:i]:
             num_hits += 1.0
             score += num_hits / (i+1.0)      
     if not actual:
         return 0.0
     return score / min(len(actual), k)
def mapk(actual ,predicted, k=3):
    zipped = []
    for i in range(0, 69532):
        zipped.append((dataX_rnn[i],dataY[i]))
    return np.mean([apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zipped])


model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(10, input_shape = (10,1)))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss = mapk, optimizer = 'adam')
```

The compile() line at the end is giving the error 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'. How do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot use numpy functions inside a keras loss, all computation has to be implemented using keras.backend functions

Comment: Thank you @Dr.Snoopy. Please also help me with the correct implementation of the loss function.